# Quadratic curve fit for 3D position and times

Tags: quadratics

I have many data points $(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_1)$, $(x_2,y_2,z_2,t_2)$, $(x_3,y_3,z_3,t_3)$, $(x_4,y_4,z_4,t_4)$ and so on.
$(x,y,z)$ is the position of a ball bouncing and hence it looks more like a multi dimensional quadratic equation. I would like to know position of the ball $(x,y,z)$ give the time $t$.

Not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One approach: find the best fit 2d polynomial in t that fits the x coordinate, then repeat for the y and z coordinates.